# Multi-line insert in Hive

Tags: hadoop, insert, hive

I am trying to insert into Hive table through files. But it so happens that the the last column in text file has data which spills across different lines.

Example data:

```
col1|col2|col3|this line is spilling into different line
               as is this, this is spilling this is spilling this is sp
               iliing and so is this
col1|col2|col3|this can be inserted without problem
```

So the spilled data is considered as a new row instead to wrapping into the last column. I tried using lines terminated by option, but cannot get this to work.

Comment: it's kind of hard to figure out which line break is part of a field and which is a record/tuple delimiter. The easy way is to escape the line break that's part of the field. Another way would be to use string identifiers (e.g. quotes) around a field that contains a delimiter (either field or record delimiter). If you can't do that, I guess you'll have to write a serde or a storage function that figures out that the data belongs with previous record if it doesn't contain delimiter for example

Comment: @ SNeumann, I guess you are right, I observed this behaiour happening over certain values and removed newline characters from them. I was able to do so thanks. But I am going to store few log values in the column and at certain times it could really be a necessity.

Answer (score 0):

This is a special case of the more general problem that having a newline (end of line/record) symbol embedded in a column. Typical csv file formats have quotation characters around the string fields, and thus detecting embedded newlines in fields is simplified by noting the newline is inside quotes.
You do not have quote characters, but you do have knowledge of the number of fields, so you can detect when a newline would lead to the premature end of the record.  But detecting the newline in the last field is harder.  You need to notice that subsequent lines do not have field separators, and assume that these following lines are part of the record.